# Why AndroidStudio launches app after second install?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently I have noticed that when I press the run icon in AndroidStudio the app does not launch.

I have to wait for the app to install after which I press run again and the app finally launches.

Any clues on what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: I have noticed that when I do the last update

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me ,(Number 1 fixed my problem) You can try 3 things

1. Reset android studio setting to its default , you can achieve this by watch this short tutorial link = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwZEliSPGwU
2. In android studio go to Build > Clean Project
3. In android studio go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ....

Hope any of them  helps .